# Relation of solutions of differential equations around different singular points

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, multivalued-functions

In order to clarify my problem, I start with an example
$$
y'-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)y=0
$$
which has two singular points, $0$ and $1$. The exact solution is not difficult to be obtained, but I would like to do the local analysis around each singular points, and find the relations between them.

Since the coefficient of the differential equation is analytical in $0<|x|<1$ and $0<|x-1|<1$, the solutions around each singular points can be represented by
$$
y_0= x^{\alpha} f(x), \qquad y_1=(x-1)^{\beta} g(x)
$$
where $f$ and $g$ are single-valued functions in corresponding ranges.

To perform the local analysis, I am going to use the seise expansions for $f$ and $g$, i.e.
$$
f=\sum_{n=0} a_n x^n,\qquad
g=\sum_{n=0} b_n x^n
$$
Then by substituting the ansatz into the original equation, I can fix the $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the coefficients of the series and the relation between the solutions at each points
$$
a_n = (-1)^n b_n
$$

**My question**: For a given differential equation
$$
y'+p(x) y=0
$$
where $p(x)$ has to two simple poles, say $x_0$ and $x_1$, if I know an asymptotic (series) solution around $x_0$, can we obtain the solution around $x_1$ without solving the equation?

Answer (score 1):

**Step one**: if $p(x)$ is an entire function, thus around some regular point $x_0$, one has a series solution of the differential equation
$$
y(x)={\bf A}\cdot {\bf X}, 
$$
where ${\bf A}=\{a_0, a_1, \ldots\}$ and ${\bf X}=\{1, (x-x_0), \ldots\}$ are two infinite dimensional vectors. The radius of convergence is $R$.
For another regular point $x_1$ located in the convergence range of above series, we can obtain a series solution at $x_1$ directly by
$$
y(x)={\bf A}\cdot {\bf J} \cdot{\bf Y},
$$
where ${\bf Y}=\{1, (x-x_1), \ldots\}$ and the component of the matrix ${\bf J}$ are $$
J_{ij}=\binom{i}{j}\Delta^{i-j}.
$$
Here $\Delta=|x_1-x_2|<R$.
If $x_1$ is not located in the convergence range,
one can make a chain, such that
$$
y(x)={\bf A}\cdot J_1 \cdot\ldots \cdot J_n \cdot {\bf Y}.
$$

**Step two**: if $p(x)$ has two simple poles, the space is extended,
at $x_0$ one has
$$
y(x) = 
\left(
 \tilde A \; A
\right)
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \tilde X \\
 X \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $\tilde A=\{0,\ldots,0,a_{-1}\}$ and $\tilde X=\{(x-x_{0})^{-\infty},\ldots,(x-x_{0})^{-1}\}$, then around $x_1$, we have
$$
y(x) = 
\left(
 \tilde A \; A
\right)
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
{\bf K} & {\bf 0}\\
{\bf 0} & {\bf J}
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
 \tilde Y \\
 Y \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the component of ${\bf K}$ is
$$
K_{ij}= \delta_{-1,i} \Delta^{j-1}.
$$
Here $\delta_{-1,i}$ is Kronecker delta. As a result, one has
$$
y(x) = 
\left(
 \tilde A \cdot {\bf K}\;\; A \cdot {\bf J}
\right)
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
 \tilde Y \\
 Y \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$